# Device for making hand notes

Tags: tablet, portable

I need some device for making hand notes, I don't need them to be OCR-ed into some editable format, just produce single images for a page, that I could store in folders that will serve as notebooks.
I've tried to use a stylus for my Android phone, but it was unusable. I was thinking about iPad + Apple pen, but this seems way too expensive. Maybe some cheaper Android tablet with a stylus would do? Surface devices also seem to be too expensive, as I won't be using them besides making notes.
Something similar to `Boogie Blackboard` would be great, but with a possibility to store multiple pages in memory and swap between them during learning sessions. Maybe there is something based on Android, that has locked OS and allows to run only a specific app for notes? Preferably, I'd like to use multiple colors while noting, but that's not a must.

Answer (score 0):

The options that come to mind are the boox e-readers that come with a stylus, or the samsung tablets. The galaxy tab s6 lite appears to be more than good enough for note taking for example.

Comment: Yeah, I was also considering it. However, it's still a bit expensive so I would like to have something cheaper. Preferably below120 EUR. But if there's no other option, then I think the S6 lite seems the most reasonable for now.

Comment: 120 euro is getting to the point where the products start lacking features or longevity, especially considering that for note taking, there's a high change you would have to buy a separate stylus, and most cheap ones do not support pressure sensitivity for example One alternative might be something like the Lenovo IdeaPad Duet. It's a bit cheaper than the s6 lite and comes with a keyboard(though no stylus)

Comment: Right, I'm not sure about the galaxy tab, as I'm afraid if I will be able to rest my palm on the display while writing. Is it possible to disable the touchscreen for certain app and make the display to react only on stylus? I think without this feature it won't be very comfortable to write for a longer time.

Comment: From my experience with the s7 almost every app that has writing options detects the stylus when it's nearby and only listens to that. Some even have pen only mode to make sure that, even when the pen is not near. your fingers are used for gestures only.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I think I'll buy the Galaxy Tab. I see that the Galaxy Tab A series is much cheaper, but I'm not sure if it has a stylus - if not, then the S series is the way to go.

Comment: Not all A series support the S pen, make sure you check before buying. From what I've checked the A8 supports, but does not include the pen.